# Advantage of using IActionResult as result type in Actions

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What's the advantage or recommendation on using `IActionResult` as the return type of a WebApi controller instead of the actual type you want to return?

Most of the examples I've seen return `IActionResult`, but when I build my first site I exclusively use View Model classes as my return types.... now I feel like I did it all wrong!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The main advantage is that you can return error/status codes or redirects/resource urls.

For example:

```
public IActionResult Get(integer id) 
{
    var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId = id).FirstOrDefault();

    if(user == null) 
    {
        // Returns HttpCode 404
        return NotFound();
    }

    // returns HttpCode 200
    return ObjectOk(user);
}
```

or

```
public IActionResult Create(User user) 
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // returns HttpCode 400
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // returns HttpCode 201
    return CreatedAtActionResult("User", "Get", new { id = user.Id} );
}
```

Comment: @KiranChalla I don't understand what we get with `IActionResult` which we can't get with `ActionResult`, is `ActionResult` limit us in some way? The other answers on the internet is not that compelling.

Comment: @HamidMosalla; Technically not much, but `IActionResult` is an interface and `ActionResult` an abstract class. While all ActionResults from MVC inherit from `ActionResult`, it is not given or guaranteed, that some 3rd party action result classes do the same, so it's always best to use the lowest possible type, here: `IActionResult`

Comment: @Tseng I know `IActionResult' is an interface and doesn't have the synchronous version of `ExecuteResult` method as opposed to `ActionResult`, I didn't find anything different from a consumer perspective, I think it might be a more of a framework design decision in which we consumer of that framework should not care about that much.

Comment: @Tseng I am late to the party, but you can also return `BadRequest` and `CreatedAtActionResult` with `IActionResult`, which makes it seem like there are no advantages with `IActionResult` then according to your examples.

Comment: @thesystem: The question was returning `IActionResult` vs returning `T`

Comment: @Tseng Got you, I misunderstood the question. Thanks for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is that you can easily test your code using a mocking framework.

And as you build your controllers, you can easily change your return object as well. IActionResult is a interface and has many implementations like JsonResult, ViewResult, FileResult and so on.

Comment: Could you use IActionResult to return (imagine the "Church-Lady" voice) a string?