# Controller response is empty although there is data to return

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

When I run this, the response is an empty `JSON`

```
[HttpGet("whattheheck")]
public async Task<MyClass> GetThings()
{
    MyClass res = await myService.GetThoseThings();
    return res;
}
```

However if I put a breakpoint in there, I can clearly see that I do have data in my `res`.
So I am not sure why it retuens empty json? Is it some casting problem? But there is no run-time excpetion or build issue.

Comment: Don't use `var`. Show us the **actual runtime type** of `res`.

Comment: _"So I am not sure why it retuens empty json?"_ - how have you configured your JSON serialization settings? Show us your `ConfigureServices` and/or `IAppBuilder` and/or _top-level-program_.

Comment: There's a lot of things that could be the problem, read up on making a [mre]. Try changing the method to return a string literal. Check if there is any middleware interfering with the response. Try starting with a fresh project and slowly adding your code back in until you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not a fan of returning Task in controllers. Here is a good existing answer why you may choose to, or not based on your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48415095/async-taskiactionresult-vs-taskt The inability to return a HTTP status code (Not Found, Unauthorized etc.) is bad for any consumer of this API.

Comment: You want: public async Task<JsonResult> GetThings() {....   return new JsonResult(res); }