# What should be returned from the Get request in the web API?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, httpclient

I am trying to return a list of objects that come from a database call that look like this:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObjectB ObjB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

Call to get item from database in web api

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<ObjectA> GetObjects([FromUri] int id)
    {
        var objs= objectRepo.All.Where(x => x.Id== id).ToList();
        return objs;
    }
```

Call from HTTPCLIENT

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2478/api/controller/");
var result= client.GetAsync("GetObjects?id=" + 5);
```

**Is there a better way to set up the get method? And how would the returned results be used once retrieved using httpclient?**

I don't need to object B as an object belonging to object A but I do need the field from object B.

Comment: What do you mean when you say *set up the get method*?

Comment: @meJustAndrew I guess I meant to say, is it okay to return a list of objects like that?And should the parameter be passed into the Uri and not from the body if that's possible.

Comment: There are advantages to returning `IActionResult` (or `ActionResult<T>` in core); check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37998841/1186321

Comment: I have answered your questions and by the way, you are missing a name for the `ObjectB` property in `ObjectA`, I will edit your question to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> is it okay to return a list of objects like that?

If you have control over the API and if you just need the `ObjectB` from your `ObjectA`, then I would suggest you to change the API to return just `ObjectB`s or even just the `Field` from `ObjectB`. For example:

```
objectRepo.All.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => x.ObjB).ToList();
```

which will return a list of `ObjectB`s.

> should the parameter be passed into the Uri and not from the body if that's possible

Yes, it can be passed in the URI using `[HttpGet("{id}")]`.

In the end you will have:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public List<ObjectB> GetObjects(int id)
{
    return objectRepo.All.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => x.ObjB).ToList();
}
```